# How do I remove all labels in my crispy form layout?

Tags: django

I'm trying to remove all the labels in my crispy forms layout. 
I've seen some similar questions regarding the labels of crispy forms, such as:

```
self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

I put this in the class in my forms.py. However I keep on getting this error message: 
    self.helper.form_show_labels = False 
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

What have I done wrong? 

This is my forms.py BTW.

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

class MyInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add that to the init

```
class MyInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyInputForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```